# What is the cardinality of a set of all monotonic functions on a segment $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, cardinals

What is the cardinality of a set of all real monotonic functions on a segment $[0,1]$?

Does it really matter that functions are monotonic?

Comment: Usually, we say monotonic or monotone functions, as "monotonous" seems to have too negative a connotation :)

Answer (score 17):

There are $(2^\omega)^\omega = 2^\omega = \mathfrak{c}$ ways to choose the values of the function on the rationals in $[0,1]$. Suppose that $f$ is a monotone function on $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$. For each irrational $x\in [0,1]$ let $$f^-(x) = \sup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,x)}f(q)$$ and $$f^+(x) = \inf_{q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(x,1]}f(q).$$ Since $f$ is monotone, the intervals $(f^-(x),f^+(x))$ are pairwise disjoint, and therefore only countable many of them can be non-empty. When $(f^-(x),f^+(x))=\varnothing$, $f^-(x)=f^+(x)$, and the only way to define $f(x)$ that preserves monotonicity is $f(x) = f^-(x) = f^+(x)$. Only the non-empty intervals $(f^-(x),f^+(x))$ permit any choice of values of $f(x)$. There are only countably many such intervals, and each permits $2^\omega = \mathfrak{c}$ choices for $f(x)$ preserving monotonicity of $f$, so $f$ can be extended in $(2^\omega)^\omega = 2^\omega = \mathfrak{c}$ ways to a monotone function on $[0,1]$. Thus, there are altogether $2^\omega \cdot 2^\omega = 2^\omega = \mathfrak{c}$ monotone functions on $[0,1]$.

The monotonicity does matter, because there are altogether $(2^\omega)^{2^\omega}=2^{\omega\cdot 2^\omega} = 2^{2^\omega} = 2^\mathfrak{c}$ functions on $[0,1]$, and $2^\mathfrak{c}>\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: A note for the readers which are less familiar, $\omega$ is used to denote $\mathbb N$ the set of natural numbers.

Comment: Actually, in this answer $\omega$ is used to denote $\aleph_0$, the cardinal of $\mathbb N$, and not $\mathbb N$ itself.

Answer (score 0):

We give an argument for the set $S=\{f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\mid f$ is monotone$\}$. This can easily be modified for the given question.

We use the notation $A\leq B$ to denote that there exists an injective map from $A$ to $B$ and the notation $A\simeq B$ to denote that there exists a bijective map from $A$ to $B$. As per our notation, a set $A$ is countable if $A\leq \mathbb N$.

We use the following result from set theory:

Let $\varphi:A\to B$ be a function and let $C$ be a set such that for every $b\in B$ we have that $\varphi^{-1}(b)\leq C$. Then we have that $A\leq B\times C$.

We also use the following result from analysis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuities_of_monotone_functions

A monotone function has at most countably many points of discontinuity.

Define $\varphi:S\to \mathbb R^\mathbb Q$ as $\varphi(f)$ is the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb Q$.

Suppose $\varphi(g)=\varphi(f)$. Then for every $x\in \mathbb Q$ we have that $g(x)=f(x)$.

So it follows that if $f$ is continuous at $a\in \mathbb R$, then we have that $g(a)=f(a)$.

As $f$ has at most countably many points of discontinuity, we see that $g$ agrees with $f$ outside a countable set.

Hence, we get that $\varphi^{-1}(f)\leq \mathbb R^\mathbb N\simeq (2^\mathbb N)^\mathbb N\simeq 2^{\mathbb N\times\mathbb N}\simeq 2^\mathbb N\simeq \mathbb R$. We also get that $\mathbb R^\mathbb Q\simeq\mathbb R^\mathbb N\simeq \mathbb R$.

So by the above mentioned result from set theory, we see that $S\leq \mathbb R^\mathbb Q\times \mathbb R\simeq \mathbb R\times \mathbb R\simeq \mathbb R$.

As we have an injective map $\psi:\mathbb R\to S$ given by $\psi(a)=c_a$ which is the constant function taking the value $a$, we get that $\mathbb R\leq S$.

Hence, by the Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein theorem it follows that $S\simeq \mathbb R$.