# Is my proof on showing that the set of monotone functions on $[a,b]$ has cardinality of continum correct?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I was given an exercise problem to show that the cardinality of the set of all monotone functions on $[a,b]$ is $\aleph$. I came out with a proof which I am not sure if it is correct.

My proof: Let $f$ be increasing on $[a,b]$ and $\{x_n\}$ are all discontinuities of $f$. Define 
$$\varphi(x) = \sum_n [f(x_n + 0) - f(x_n)] \theta(x - x_n) + \sum_n[f(x_n) - f(x_n - 0)]\theta_1(x - x_n),$$
where $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside function and $\theta_1(x) = 1 - \theta(-x)$, and put $g = f - \varphi$, then $\varphi$ is an increasing jump function and $g$ is an increasing continuous function. And we see different monotone functions correspond to different decompositions. On the one hand, $C[a,b]$ has cardinality of continum. On the other hand, we claim that the set of all jump functions on $[a,b]$ also has cardinality $\aleph$, **as the process of defining a jump function can be viewed as choosing countably many different points from $[a,b]$ first, and then assigning the corresponding coefficients, so there are $\aleph \cdot \aleph = \aleph$ ways of defining a jump function**. Hence by the decomposition, the cardinality of the set of monotone functions cannot exceed $\aleph \cdot \aleph = \aleph$. Since obviously the cardinality is greater than $\aleph$, the proof is completed.

I am not sure whether my argument(**the bold part**) is correct. I have not studied set theory systematically(All the knowledge I know comes from books on real analysis). Please help me on verifying this proof. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The size continuum is denoted $2^{\aleph_0}$ I don't think a plain old $\aleph$ denotes anything at all.

Comment: @Quinn Culver Yeah, I realised that after posting and deleted :)

Comment: @James: $\aleph$ is a less known notation for the cardinality of the continuum. But it's not uncommon, especially in introductory level set theory.

Comment: Well, you learn something new every day. Is it old notation? I've been through the introductory part of set theory but don't recall ever seeing it.

Comment: What about $y=ax$ for $a\in\Bbb R$? That certainly shows that the cardinality of monotone functions is _at least_ $\frak c$. You already know that $C[a,b]$ has cardinality $\frak c$. If you can slightly generalize and show that the set of functions with countably many discontinuity points is at most $\frak c$, you'd be done. I don't know if this is true. I'm trying to prove it.

Comment: @Bryan I have considered a similar idea, but my intuition said that such set has cardinality $2^{\aleph}$. Nor have I shown it.

Comment: A monotone function has at most a countable number of discontinuities.

Comment: @James Probably because I am using textbooks that have ages. You may see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph#Mathematics) for more information

Comment: @copper.hat I am considering the **set of all monotone functions** instead of set of discontinuities of certain monotone function :-)

Comment: @mathmajor: I understand, but since every monotone function can be represented by a continuous function and a sequence of reals (well, pairs of reals), this lets you bound the cardinality.

Comment: @mathmajor My idea wouldn't work. That collection has cardinality $2^{\frak c}$.

Comment: @copper.hat I see. I think the *sequence of reals* that you are referring to is actually the same thing as what I called "jump function".

Comment: @mathmajor: Yes, and ${\frak c}^2 = {\frak c}$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/71163/27978.

Comment: @Bryan: As far as I can see the number of functions with at most countably many discontinuities _is_ $\mathfrak c$. If it's $2^{\mathfrak c}$, then there's a bug somewhere in my answer ...

Comment: Henning is correct (see the above answer for details).

Comment: @HenningMakholm you're right. There's a bug in mine.

Comment: Are you allowed to use (or can you prove) that every monotone function is a pointwise limit of continuous functions? If so, then there are no more monotone functions than there are sequences of continuous functions, and the number of the latter is $c^{{\aleph}_0}= \left( 2^{{\aleph}_0} \right)^{{\aleph}_0} = 2^{{\aleph}_0 \cdot{{\aleph}_0}} = 2^{{\aleph}_0} = c.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic strategy looks like it works, but I think it would be simpler to say something like:

It is clear that there are *at least* $\mathfrak c$ monotone functions.

On the other hand, every monotone function has at most countably many points of discontinuity, so it is fully specified by the combination of (a) its values at every rational point, (b) the locations of its discontinuities, and (c) its values at every point of discontinuity. So we can specify it using $\omega\cdot 3$ real numbers -- that is, countably many -- and the set of real *sequences* has cardinality $\mathfrak c$. So there can be *at most* $\mathfrak c$ monotone functions.

(To unfold such a specification: The specification directly gives the function values at a dense set of points that includes all discontinuities. So the only function values that we need to reconstruct are at points that we know the function is *continuous* at. For these points we can find the function value as a limit of the points we know; and there are enough of them to find the limit because we know densely many values).

---

If we're working without the Axiom of Choice there's the additional snag (in either your formulation or mine) that we need to be able to choose a function that takes each monotonic function to a *particular* one of the many sequences of reals that define it.

For this we need to be able to select a canonical *enumeration* of the points of discontinuity for all monotone functions at once. But since every discontinuity is a jump discontinuity we can do that. First compress the range of the function into a finite interval, say, by composing it with $y\mapsto e^y/(e^y+1)$; then order the discontinuities in order of decreasing jump height, and for jumps of the same height, in order of increasing $x$.